# Embedding Bokeh Server as a library: Tornado error

Tags: python, bokeh

I am following Bokeh's User Guide.

In "Embedding Bokeh Server as a Library" at http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#embedding-bokeh-server-as-a-library 
it refers to a demo where a Bokeh server is embedded in Flask (https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/0.12.6/examples/howto/server_embed/flask_embed.py)

It should be straightforward but I get a Tornado error if launched with `python flask_embed.py`. **Anybody has an idea WHY?**

The page on the browser is correctly launched but there is no plot.

This is the short error message:

```
ERROR:tornado.application:Uncaught exception GET /bkapp/autoload.js?bokeh-autoload-element=3a711948-3668-4f63-8d0c-8cd1584fb92d&bokeh-app-path=/bkapp&bokeh-absolute-url=http://localhost:5006/bkapp (127.0.0.1)
HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:5006', method='GET', uri='/bkapp/autoload.js?bokeh-autoload-element=3a711948-3668-4f63-8d0c-8cd1584fb92d&bokeh-app-path=/bkapp&bokeh-absolute-url=http://localhost:5006/bkapp', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='127.0.0.1', headers={'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Host': 'localhost:5006', 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Referer': 'http://localhost:8080/', 'Cookie': 'username-localhost-8888="2|1:0|10:1501067928|23:username-localhost-8888|44:Y2EwOTUzN2YzNWRiNGQyMDgxZWEyOGMzZDJkOTI4ZWY=|f4f981dd915dc777c70e605b7135bcbbc076b3fe3482999e5ca557cb4abd518e"; _xsrf=2|c711b8e7|f913ccc5c9cc32532c1e67bbd75b6051|1500889250'})
...
HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
ERROR:tornado.access:500 GET /bkapp/autoload.js?bokeh-autoload-element=3a711948-3668-4f63-8d0c-8cd1584fb92d&bokeh-app-path=/bkapp&bokeh-absolute-url=http://localhost:5006/bkapp (127.0.0.1)
```

And here the whole traceback:

```
Opening Flask app with embedded Bokeh application on http://localhost:8080/
ERROR:tornado.application:Uncaught exception GET /bkapp/autoload.js?bokeh-autoload-element=3a711948-3668-4f63-8d0c-8cd1584fb92d&bokeh-app-path=/bkapp&bokeh-absolute-url=http://localhost:5006/bkapp (127.0.0.1)
HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:5006', method='GET', uri='/bkapp/autoload.js?bokeh-autoload-element=3a711948-3668-4f63-8d0c-8cd1584fb92d&bokeh-app-path=/bkapp&bokeh-absolute-url=http://localhost:5006/bkapp', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='127.0.0.1', headers={'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Host': 'localhost:5006', 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Referer': 'http://localhost:8080/', 'Cookie': 'username-localhost-8888="2|1:0|10:1501067928|23:username-localhost-8888|44:Y2EwOTUzN2YzNWRiNGQyMDgxZWEyOGMzZDJkOTI4ZWY=|f4f981dd915dc777c70e605b7135bcbbc076b3fe3482999e5ca557cb4abd518e"; _xsrf=2|c711b8e7|f913ccc5c9cc32532c1e67bbd75b6051|1500889250'})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alessandro/git-files/python/study_graph2/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1511, in _execute
    result = yield result
  File "/home/alessandro/git-files/python/study_graph2/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/home/alessandro/git-files/python/study_graph2/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 238, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "/home/alessandro/git-files/python/study_graph2/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1063, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/home/alessandro/git-files/python/study_graph2/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/server/views/autoload_js_handler.py", line 31, in get
    session = yield self.get_session()
  File "/home/alessandro/git-files/python/study_graph2/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/home/alessandro/git-files/python/study_graph2/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 238, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "/home/alessandro/git-files/python/study_graph2/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1063, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/home/alessandro/git-files/python/study_graph2/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/server/views/session_handler.py", line 40, in get_session
    session = yield self.application_context.create_session_if_needed(session_id, self.request)
  File "/home/alessandro/git-files/python/study_graph2/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/home/alessandro/git-files/python/study_graph2/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 238, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "/home/alessandro/git-files/python/study_graph2/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1069, in run
    yielded = self.gen.send(value)
  File "/home/alessandro/git-files/python/study_graph2/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/server/application_context.py", line 177, in create_session_if_needed
    self._application.initialize_document(doc)
  File "/home/alessandro/git-files/python/study_graph2/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/application/application.py", line 121, in initialize_document
    h.modify_document(doc)
  File "/home/alessandro/git-files/python/study_graph2/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/application/handlers/function.py", line 16, in modify_document
    self._func(doc)
  File "main.py", line 22, in modify_doc
    df = pd.read_csv(data_url, parse_dates=True, index_col=0)
  File "/home/alessandro/git-files/python/study_graph2/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 655, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/home/alessandro/git-files/python/study_graph2/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 392, in _read
    filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression)
  File "/home/alessandro/git-files/python/study_graph2/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 186, in get_filepath_or_buffer
    req = _urlopen(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 435, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 548, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 473, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 556, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
ERROR:tornado.access:500 GET /bkapp/autoload.js?bokeh-autoload-element=3a711948-3668-4f63-8d0c-8cd1584fb92d&bokeh-app-path=/bkapp&bokeh-absolute-url=http://localhost:5006/bkapp (127.0.0.1) 425.75ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the page is served, the server tries to load CSV data from an external URL using Pandas. I'm not sure whether this example worked before, but right now it seems that `pd.read_csv` does not encode URL query, so the server is unable to treat characters `>` and `<`. You can either replace the characters manually (refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) or use some library for it, like Python's `urllib`.

Comment: Thank you, Eugene, you got it. I didn't yet check the URL, but loading a local CSV file solves the problem. I thought that the URL in the traceback had something to do with the Bokeh server, not with the data file.